# CSS Code Showing

Tags: html, css

My CSS code for  `.header` and `.mtstyle` are now showing in my header when I preview. Nothing I have done has fixed the issue. This just started to happen. Thoughts? Also, is there a way to combine the `a:link` css into one line? Thanks.

```css
.header {
  position: absolute;
  height: 45px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.mtstyle {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left:15px;  
}

/* unvisited link */
.mtlstyle a:link {
  color: #3399CC;
}

/* visited link */
.mtlstyle a:visited {
  color: #3399CC;
}

/* mouse over link */
.mtlstyle a:hover {
  color: none;
}

/* selected link */
.mtlstyle a:active {
  color: #3399CC;
}

.mtlstyle a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mtlstyle a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mtlstyle a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mtlstyle a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="mtstyle">
    <div class="mtlstyle">
      <h1><a href="index.php">Title</h1></a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Nothing I have done has fixed the issue` ....  What is your issue by the way?

Comment: @JonesVinothJoseph when I preview my page, .header and .mtstyle css code shows up right above the title.

Comment: you need to wrap your css rules into `<style>...</style>` tag

Comment: @Mickeyatty I seem to have fallen onto deaf ears. You expect free help, then you need to give back to the community. This isn't all "take take take". When you accept answers, you get points and they get rewarded also. Others may not want to help you later on, should they check your track record. Take this as being a "Stack pro tip".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to code, always try to close your open tags before put another tag in it! 
For starter your HTML is incorrect in this line: 
`<h1><a href="index.php">Title</h1></a>` 
It should be: 
`<h1><a href="index.php">Title</a></h1>` 
you must enclose `a` tag first then close the `h1`.
And you can always create CSS for multiple classes or behaviour with use of "`,`", like this:

```
a:hover, a:visited, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: thank you. I didn't even notice I didn't close my tag or put the </a> before the </h1>. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Mickeyatty And as of your problem since it seems you put your code in the index page, are you sure you put your code in a `<style>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Delete this

```
/* unvisited link */
     .mtlstyle a:link {
     color: #3399CC;
     }

     /* visited link */
     .mtlstyle a:visited {
      color: #3399CC;
     }
```

Comment: That won't help, because then you won't be overriding the default styles in the UA stylesheet any more.